# why styled component styling not adding

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i was scratching my head from the last 2 hours that why this 3 rd party styled component is not adding i it .have a look

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'
const StyleDiv =styled.div`
@media(max-width:600px){
body{
background-color: red;
}
}`
const Person= (props)=>{
return <StyleDiv>
<h1 onClick={props.click}>i am {props.name} and {props.age} years old as you  know me as {props.children} </h1>
<input type="text" onChange={props.changed} />
</StyleDiv>
} 
export default Person;
```

Comment: is your issue that the background color is not showing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put selectors within the template string without the ampersand, they will refer to children of the component. https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting

Basically you can't select body within your div and you probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot apply global styles like this to a component, for applying global styles (i.e. styles to body, html etc.) `styled-components` gives a `createGlobalStyles` utility, it can be used like this:

```
import { createGlobalStyles } from 'styled-components';

const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
`;

// Render GlobalStyles to the root lvvel of your app
ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <GlobalStyles />
    <App /> 
  </>,
  document.getElementById('root');
);
```

Hope it helps :)